# Does Ball park estimate ever help

Tags: estimation

In our projects we are often asked to give ball park estimates for activities. My question does it really help in taking decisions based on the estimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes as pointed out above.

No if the client later says "Oh, but that's much more than the X days you initially estimated"

You need to be careful in explaining and agreeing on what "ballpark" really means

Answer (score 2):

Yes .. it can help to give rough estimates to the client but later on these estimates can show upto +/- 50% variation.

But it can help to gauge the size of the project and roughly manday efforts

Comment: Also, with experience, your estimates will get slightly better over time.

Answer (score 1):

Something to add to the existing responses.

**Pros**:

1. Helpful for a teamleader to assess
   the number of resources needed for a
   set of activities.
2. Useful to assess
   whether a task would fit in a pre
   defined timeline

**Cons**:

1. Very rough estimate
2. Need to be very careful while sharing with the customer.

Answer (score 1):

I often use these ballpark estimates to give a quick price quote to a client, when based on models such as WMFP or COCOMO-II they can also help me make an unbiased assessment.